# Why would a new Date.toDateString() return the UTC date?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the amazing [bootstrap calendar](https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar) plugin and I've noticed that it is seeing the current date as the UTC date, not the local date.  I always thought that javascript Date was local so what would be causing new Date()).toDateString() to be UTC date?  Thanks

```
if(date.toDateString() == (new Date()).toDateString()) {
        console.log(date.toDateString());
        console.log(date.toString());
        console.log(new Date().toDateString());
        addClass("today", classes);
}
```

If I add logging I get this, but it stills show it as the 5th

Wed Jun 04 2014

Wed Jun 04 2014 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Standard Time)

Wed Jun 04 2014

Is it possible that another library is overwriting the default toString()\toDateString().  I have both moment.js and date.js include on the page?

Comment: ... more likely to be helpful (although probably not) - bootstrap calendar appears to generally use `-` for formatting dates to string - a slightly odd choice, considering that specific date format is the *one* format that is likely to cause issues if ever parsed back into a `Date`. Although the library itself doesn't appear to ever send string parameters to `Date()`, `new Date("2014-06-04")` for example *will* be parsed as UTC rather than local. What's the value of `date` if you log it to the console before the "today" check?

Comment: @JimmiTh Thanks for the help, I added logging and added it to the question.

Comment: What exactly is your question? The string format you posted seems accurate. I get `Wed Jun 04 2014 23:29:11 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)`

Comment: @Halcyon  My question is why is it adding class 'today' to the 5th vs the 4th.  It turns out the values are correct so maybe the plugin has a bug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I always thought that javascript Date was local

No. JavaScript dates are timezone-independent. Only its methods that have to do conversion care about the timezone, e.g. `toUTCString()` yields UTC and `toString()` yields a user-locale-timezone dependent representation; similarly `getUTCHours()` vs. `getHours()`.

> so what would be causing `(new Date()).toDateString()` to be UTC date?

Nothing, I hope. [`toDateString`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.5.3) returns the date in the current, local timezone. If that is yielding the UTC value, either a) you are in UTC+0 or b) the date object it was called on represent the wrong timestamp in the first place.

> Is it possible that another library is overwriting the default toString()\toDateString().

Yes, but you must never overwrite built-in methods (unless they're really buggy and you want to use a spec-conforming polyfill).

> My question is why the bootstrap calendar plugin adding class 'today' to the 5th vs the 4th.

<s>Probably because it show the calender in UTC days, not local ones.</s> No idea, the plugin is using local dates everywhere in the source.

Comment: You're correct to say no to overwriting native functionality, but it's not correct to say no to the question of whether it's possible. This library does modify the `Date` prototype, though not that specific method. Perhaps it'd be better to say it's possible, but strongly advised against, and that particular library doesn't seem to be the culprit.

Comment: The library does add *additional*, custom methods to the `Date.prototype`, yes, but it does not overwrite existing ones.